# How can I delete a file on client?

Tags: shell, ssh

After copying files from `/home/foo/bar` the original files on the client must be deleted, EXCEPT for file `/home/foo/bar/special_file`. This file must remain on the client. I want to delete all the files in a directory, keeping only a specific folder safe.

How can I do that? I can use `wipe -rcfs *` but it will wipe everything in the folder that is not desired.

Comment: FYI: All the methods for doing this are covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325216/rm-all-files-except-some

Comment: When deleting files from Unix the command you should think of is `rm` not `wipe`, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ssh user@remote bash -c 'cd /home/foo/bar; shopt -s extglob; rm !(special_file)'
```

#### Details

From the [Bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), this feature is called [`extglob`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching).

Answer (score 0):

Set `GLOBIGNORE='*/.:*/..:special_file'` and then `cd /home/foo/bar ; wipe -rcfs *` if you're using bash.

Comment: sorry man.!! but it is still wiping out all the contents in the directory.

Comment: @Ricky - if this didn't work then why did you accept it? Glenn's answer is the right way to do this, using `!(special_file)`

Comment: sorry @slm. but i am new here. i did not know much about these buttons.